# Jquery request to django gets 403 error even after disabling CSRF

Tags: jquery, django, json, csrf

I am new to Django and working on a small project where a JQuery client sends a JSON request (username and password) to my DJango server page. But, Django spits out a 403 error every time. This is the error I get:

```
 POST /html/localhost HTTP/1.1" 403 2326
```

This is frustrating as it is a very basic setup that involves client <-> server communication.

My client-side form:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="vs.djangoserver" method="post"> 
User: <input type="text" name="username" /> 
Pass: <input type="password" name="password" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

vs.djangoserver is mapped correctly (or so I think), and I can navigate to it using Django's test server.

The JQuery code that sends the form's fields as JSON is here:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: formAction,
       data: printableJSONStr,
       dataType: "json",
       beforeSend: function(x,y) {
         if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
           x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
         }
       },
       success: post_submit
     });
```

What I am confused about is how to POST to a page that Django creates and serve on the fly. I am awre of Django's CSRF protection, and I added this to my Django's view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import
@csrf_exempt
def .......
```

One other thing I tried was to point to a non-existent action in the client form. In that case, I got the same 403 error (versus a 404 as I expected).

I am looking for a simple (but complete) example where JQuery points to a django's page and it works!